# Error in actionPerformed while using createStatement

Tags: java, sql, database, actionlistener

I'm trying to connect my Tic-Tac-Toe server with a database to enter details of players. I created a button in my server which adds players to the database while the server is running. Here's an excerpt of my code and the error:

```
    public class TicTacToeServer extends JFrame {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String player1Name;
String player2Name;
static JTextArea jtaLog;
int winState = 0;
static JButton addPlayer;
static JButton delPlayer;
static JButton getResults;
static JButton delResults;
static JButton cumulativeResults;
public static int PLAYER1 = 1;
public static int PLAYER2 = 2;
public static int PLAYER1_WON = 1;
public static int PLAYER2_WON = 2;
public static int DRAW = 3;
public static int CONTINUE = 4;
private final String username = "user";
private final String password = "1234";
private Connection con;
private final String ID = "ID";
private final String Name = "Name";
private final String Surname = "Surname";
private final String Username = "Username";
private final String Password = "Password";
private final String Email = "Email";
static TicTacToeServer frame;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    frame = new TicTacToeServer();
    frame.connectToDB();

}

public TicTacToeServer() throws SQLException {

    jtaLog = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtaLog);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 300);
    setTitle("TicTacToeServer");
    setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    addPlayer = new JButton("Add Player");
    delPlayer = new JButton("Delete Player");
    getResults = new JButton("Obtain Results");
    delResults = new JButton("Delete Results");
    cumulativeResults = new JButton("Obtain Cumulative Results");
    panel.add(addPlayer);
    panel.add(delPlayer);
    panel.add(getResults);
    panel.add(delResults);
    panel.add(cumulativeResults);
    addPlayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {
            Object source = click.getSource();
            if (source == addPlayer) {

                System.out.println("Please provide unique ID for the user:");
                int id = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Please type in the first name:");
                String firstName = scan.next();
                System.out.println("Please type in the surname:");
                String surname = scan.next();
                System.out.println("Please type in the username:");
                String username = scan.next();
                System.out.println("Please type in the password:");
                String password = scan.next();
                System.out.println("Please type in the email:");
                String email = scan.next();
                **try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)) {**
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PLAYERS");
                    rs.moveToInsertRow();
                    rs.updateInt(ID, id);
                    rs.updateString(Name, firstName);
                    rs.updateString(Surname, surname);
                    rs.updateString(Username, username);
                    rs.updateString(Password, password);
                    rs.updateString(Email, email);
                    rs.insertRow();

                } catch (SQLException err) {
                    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
                }

            }

        }
    });
    delPlayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {
            Object source = click.getSource();
            if (source == delPlayer) {
                System.out.println("Enter the user ID that should be removed:");
                int id = scan.nextInt();

                **try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE))** {
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PLAYERS");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        if (rs.getInt("ID") == id) {
                            rs.deleteRow();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException err) {
                    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    });
    //getResults.addActionListener(this);
    //delResults.addActionListener(this);
    //cumulativeResults.addActionListener(this);


public void connectToDB() throws SQLException {
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Project", username, password);

    }

}
```

As highlighted in the code (in **), my error indicates that it's got something to do with this line:

```
    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE))
```

Here's my error message:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tictactoeserver.TicTacToeServer$1.actionPerformed(TicTacToeServer.java:91)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Other than indicating the aforementioned line in the first error line (regarding actionPerformed, line 91), I'm not sure how to go about this. How do I negate this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a `NullPointerException` since variable `con` is null. You created a connection but you didn't assign it to `con`. Instead write

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(...)
```